# How to compare alignment between a normal vector and inertia tensor

Tags: differential-geometry, classical-mechanics

I'm working with data of biological cells, and we want to measure how the shape of a cell aligns with the normal vector of its surrounding tissue (where the cell is at the boundary).

One idea was to compare the normal vector $n$ with the inertia tensor $I = \int_\Omega \rho(x) (\Vert \mathbf{x}\Vert^2 \mathrm{Id_3} - \mathbf{x} \otimes \mathbf{x})  \, \mathrm{d}{\mathbf{x}}$.

If the inertia matrix has eigenvalues $\lambda_1 \geq \lambda_2 \geq \lambda_3$ with corresponding (ONB) of eigenvectors $v_1, v_2, v_3$, then the naive idea was to just compute the angle
$$
\text{alignment} = \angle( v_1, n).
$$

**Now, that doesn't work well in cases where the two largest eigenvalues are close to each other.** In that situation, the normal seems pretty much in alignment with the cell's body, but the naive alignment measure doesn't show it.

**Question:** Is there a geometric structure that we could make use of to compare the inertia matrix with a vector?

Ideally the comparison should be such that:

- it is invariant under scaling of the cell (e.g. invariant under space scaling $\mathbf{x} \mapsto \mu \mathbf{x}$)
- optimal: it should be easy to interpret, e.g. for example what is the maximal value and minimal value of the metric.

Intuitively I would like to compute $I \wedge n$ but I don't really know if that is justified.

**Ideas:**

- We could compute $n^T I n$ which would kind of tell us the kinetic energy of rotation around the normal axis. If the cell is aligned with that axis, then this value should be small.
- maybe something like
  $$\text{alignment} = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^3 \lambda_i \angle(v_i,n)}{\sum_{i=1}^3 \lambda_i}?$$